# CSS display:table-cell, set height and overflow:hidden, doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, clip

I want to clip an element if its children's content is too large, but it's not working in `display:table-cell` elements. Here is an example on JsFiddle:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Perhaps/rycuwq3w/)

```css
.table{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:200px;
}
.cell{
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: top;
      position: relative;
      height:200px;
      overflow:hidden;
}
.container{
  height:100%;
  background-color:red;
}
.container img{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="container"> 
          <img src="http://img5.imgtn.bdimg.com/it/u=172690696,3532821463&fm=206&gp=0.jpg" />
           <img src="http://img5.imgtn.bdimg.com/it/u=172690696,3532821463&fm=206&gp=0.jpg" />
            <img src="http://img5.imgtn.bdimg.com/it/u=172690696,3532821463&fm=206&gp=0.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Anybody Please tell where am I wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You can't apply height to the `display: table-cell` container. So, instead apply height to the `.container` element. like `.container{ height: 200px }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work, we have to use position:relative for table and position:absolute for table cell item. Also in your code, I've removed container's height: 100% which is of no use. Here's the preview and [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/530vbo5z/).

```css
.table{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:200px;
    position: relative;
}
.cell{
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: top;
      position: absolute;
      height:200px;
      width: 100%;
      overflow-y:scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container{
  background-color:red;
}
.container img{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="container"> 
          <img src="http://img5.imgtn.bdimg.com/it/u=172690696,3532821463&fm=206&gp=0.jpg" />
           <img src="http://img5.imgtn.bdimg.com/it/u=172690696,3532821463&fm=206&gp=0.jpg" />
            <img src="http://img5.imgtn.bdimg.com/it/u=172690696,3532821463&fm=206&gp=0.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I know how to solve the question,I don't know why I set height,and set overflow,but it's not work...

Answer (score -1):

change your css display type.

```
.table{
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height:200px;
}
.cell{
  display:block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.container{
  height:100%;
  background-color:red;
}
.container img{
  display:block;
}
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/palak6041/rycuwq3w/1/)